# Universal link not working for multiple apps

Tags: macos, ios-universal-links

I have created a universal link which I m using for two different applications in macOS. Below is the apple-app-site-association file for the same:

```
{
"applinks":{
   "apps":[],
     "details":[
        {
           "appID":"E5R4JF6D5K.com.demo.App1",
           "paths":[
                "/app1/*"
            ]
        },
        {
          "appID":"E5R4JF6D5K.world.demo.App2",
          "paths":[
              "/app2/*"
           ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

After creating this file in my server and providing the same Url in my associated domain capability for both my application, when I try to launch my applications using the link then only the first application is getting launched everytime. The second application is never launched.

for Url with http://custom.com/app1/... it redirects to first app.

for Url with http://custom.com/app2/... it redirects to browser.

I tried uninstalling the first app, but then it always directs in browser. I tried a separate url for both apps, and it works fine.

I m not able to figure out the problem. The apple documentation says that it is possible to have two application linked to a common domain. Any help?